# How can I limit the rotation on the Y axis so that the player can't continuously spin the camera in Unity

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have an upcoming project that I have to present on Monday and this is the last bug I have to resolve. It would be nice if someone could help me out, and could teach me how to apply an axis limiter, thanks in advance everyone.

The issue is that the camera can spin 360 degrees

Below is my current code that controls the camera

```cs
public float sensitivity = 30.0f;
private GameObject cam;
float rotX, rotY;

private void Start()
{
    sensitivity = sensitivity * 1.5f;
    Cursor.visible = false; // For convenience
}

private void Update()
{
    rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
    rotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;
    //Apply rotations
    CameraRotation(cam, rotX, rotY);
}

private void CameraRotation(GameObject cam, float rotX, float rotY)
{
    //Rotate the player horizontally
    transform.Rotate(0, rotX * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    //Rotate the players view vertically
    cam.transform.Rotate(-rotY * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: this is not a fully documented answer, but try attaching to the camera's update function an if that checks whether it's surpassed 180 degrees or -180 degrees on both horizontal and vertical axis by checking its transform component's rotation. good luck!

Comment: I can't get it to work. Tried lots of fixes but with no luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding logical clamping to this makes it quite a bit clearer to read through, this method clamps the vertical rotation between 60 and -60 degrees, the comments should help in modifying it if you need

I ended up jumping into Unity to test it this time, instead of going off the top of my head

```
void CameraRotation(GameObject cam, float rotX, float rotY)
{
    //Rotate the player horizontally
    transform.Rotate(0, rotX * Time.deltaTime, 0);
    //Rotate the players view vertically
    cam.transform.Rotate(-rotY * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);

    //Grab current rotation in degrees
    Vector3 currentRot = cam.transform.localRotation.eulerAngles;
    //If (x-axis > (degreesUp*2) && x-axis < (360-degreesUp))
    if (currentRot.x > 120 && currentRot.x < 300) currentRot.x = 300;
    //else if (x-axis < (degreesDown*2) && x-axis > (degreesDown))
    else if (currentRot.x < 120 && currentRot.x > 60) currentRot.x = 60;
    //Set clamped rotation
    cam.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRot);
}
```

Goodluck with the project

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, added this to my code but it doesn't seem to do anything..

Comment: @BojanVasoski Sorry about that, I just realised that my original answer just limits the speed/amount of rotation with the use of `.Rotate`

Comment: What do you suggest I do?

Comment: @BojanVasoski I've updated my previous submission above, hopefully I haven't overlooked something again!

Comment: Tried it, now I cant look up/down at all, like its completely locked.

Comment: The second solution doesn't do anything too I can look around 360 like before..

Comment: @BojanVasoski Damn, I'm really not helping out much today, just creating more and more problems that need solving. I'm seeing even more issues with my answers... let me update them again

Comment: @BojanVasoski Sorry for this back and forth, I finally decided to jump into Unity and get it right this time, rather than going off the top of my head. I've updated my answer which should work quite nicely for you!

Comment: Wow, that worked!!! Thank you for solving this issue for me, it was one of the last bugs in my project. Thanks so much again, and sorry for wasting a portion of your time...All the best wishes, stay safe and best of luck kind stranger. Good karma will follow you for you whole life. Made my day, can't be happier thanks!!!! Love you<3.

Comment: No problem at all, thank you for giving me a reason to look into Unity again. Thank you very much, and the same to you. Good luck with it all!